# How to get validators list which nominator delegated

Tags: polkadot-js, validator, nominator

I want to get validator address list from nominator address using PolkadotJS/api.

How can I get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below are a couple of options of how to use the following Substrate storage query `api.query.staking.nominators(AccountId32):Option<PalletStakingNominations>` from the Polkadot.js API docs [here](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/substrate/storage#nominatorsaccountid32-optionpalletstakingnominations) to get the list of validators that have been nominated by a given nominator stash address.

**Option 1:**

- Go to https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=wss%3A%2F%2Frpc.polkadot.io#/js
- Note: Replace `wss%3A%2F%2Frpc.polkadot.io` with the WS endpoints for RPC connections of the chain they are using to nominate on
- Paste the code snippet below, replacing the `ALICE` address with an address that is actively nominating
- Click the play icon
- View the output in the terminal on the right that will list the validators they have nominated.

```js
const ALICE = '5GrwvaEF5zXb26Fz9rcQpDWS57CtERHpNehXCPcNoHGKutQY';
const validators = await api.query.staking.nominators(ALICE);
if (validators.toJSON() && validators.toJSON().hasOwnProperty("targets")) {
  console.log(`stash account ${ALICE} has nominated the following validators\n\n`,
    JSON.stringify(validators.toJSON()["targets"], null, 2));
} else {
  console.log(`stash account ${ALICE} has not nominated any validators`);
}
```

**Option 2:**

- Alternatively install Node.js and create a program:

```bash
mkdir nominated-validators-for-account
cd nominated-validators-for-account
yarn init
touch index.js
yarn add @polkadot/api
npm pkg set 'scripts.start'='node index.js'
npm pkg set 'type'='module'
```

- Paste the following code in your terminal to add it to index.js

  - Note: Replace `wss://rpc.polkadot.io` with the WS endpoint for RPC connections of the chain they are using to nominate on

```js
cat <<EOT >> index.js

import { ApiPromise, WsProvider } from '@polkadot/api';

const ALICE = '5GrwvaEF5zXb26Fz9rcQpDWS57CtERHpNehXCPcNoHGKutQY';

async function main () {
  const wsProvider = new WsProvider('wss://rpc.polkadot.io');
  const api = await ApiPromise.create({ provider: wsProvider });
  const validators = await api.query.staking.nominators(ALICE);
  if (validators.toJSON() && validators.toJSON().hasOwnProperty("targets")) {
    console.log(`ALICE account ${ALICE} has nominated the following validators\n\n`,
      JSON.stringify(validators.toJSON()["targets"], null, 2));
  } else {
    console.log(`ALICE account ${ALICE} has not nominated any validators`);
  }
}

main().catch(console.error).finally(() => process.exit());

EOT
```

Run the program and view the output:

```bash
yarn start
```